# Displaying tr elements on the same line

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-tables

I am working with a legacy html code which uses tables extensively for layout. For the page I'm making I unfortunately have to call one of these legacy systems which returns the output in table with multiple tr's.

I got it to align on the same line in both Firefox/Chrome by using

```
display: inline;
float: left;
```

But it still doesn't work in IE9 (I haven't tested with other versions of IE). Is there anything to force IE to display both `<tr>` elements on the same line?

Answer (score 1):

I would try

`display:inline-block;`

*Untested*

You might also consider using javascript to manipulate the elements once the DOM is rendered.

**EDIT**

The other thing you might do is set a specific `width` on the `tr`s.  IE9 might be giving them a default `100%`, so less than `50%` each if there are two of them, etc.

Comment: tried it.. didnt seem to work. currently i have the style on tr elements.

Comment: Does it help to set it on both `tr` _and_ `td`?

Comment: See my edit Sainath.  Don't think that would make a difference @powerbuoy

Comment: ya, width seems to be the problem. Even after I set width to 45% on both tr/td.. IE still has both the rows at the width of table.

Comment: At this point, it might be wise the set the width with `!important`